# What kind of views are used in this picture

Tags: ios, xcode, view

[image: cool app]

You can scroll the upper images to the left and when you tap them it opens in fullscreen (you can scroll in fullscreen again)

I get the images thrue json as a link so...
How can i make something like this ? some tips/tutorials ?

Beneath the images is a tableview right ?

are these just 2 views in a controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is a `UIScrollView` with a set of images in it. It has horizontal scrolling enabled. You can add a tap gesture on the images to give the zoom feature.

Second one can be a `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` based on the content. These two views can be added as subviews of the `self.view.`

Check [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) for tutorials on iOS.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain the reason for down vote?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a horizontal `UIScrollView` (tutorial [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)) and a `UITableView`. So yes I believe 2 views would be enough.